# Capturing a copy of parameter pack

Tags: c++, lambda, capture

My class has a member of a type `optional<A>`. I'm trying to implement function `emplaceWhenReady` which gets list of parameters to A's constructor, but the non-trivial part is that `A` can be only initialized after a certain event. When `emplaceWhenReady` is invoked before the event, I need to somehow capture the initialization values.

For single constructor parameter the code can be written as:

```
struct B {
   bool _ready;
   std::optional<A> _a;
   std::function<void()> _fInit;

   template<typename ARG>
   void emplaceWhenReady1(ARG&& arg) {
      if (_ready) {
         _a.emplace(std::forward<ARG>(arg));
      } else {
         _fInit = [this, argCopy = std::forward<ARG>(arg)]() {
            _a.emplace(std::move(argCopy));
      };
    }
};
```

and `_fInit()` can be now invoked when the class becomes `_ready`. But I fail to write similar code for multiple parameters:

```
// Fails to compile
template<typename... ARGS>
void emplaceWhenReady(ARGS&&... args) {
    if (_ready) {
        _a.emplace(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
    } else {
        _fInit = [this, argsCopy = std::forward<ARGS>(args)...]() {
            _a.emplace(std::move(argsCopy)...);
        };
    }
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Fi3o1S

```
error: expected ',' or ']' in lambda capture list
       _fInit = [this, argsCopy = std::forward<ARGS>(args)...]() {
                                                          ^
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't really understand how to test, you are trying to emplace a variadic list in optional?

Comment: You know `std::function` imposes a copyability-requirement? Anyway, look at `<tuple>` and specifically `std::apply()`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour thanks, but from what I see the problem in that question is different, as they only need to forward the parameters into the lambda, but not to capture a copy of the parameters

Comment: :-( that is what I get for speed commenting

Comment: @Deduplicator I crated a version where the copy of parameters is stored with `make_tuple` and it uses `std::apply` as you suggested: https://godbolt.org/z/qC7I8L seems like a working solution to me, thanks!

Comment: Well, craft a self-answer then, if you have the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at proposal [p0780: Allow pack expansion in lambda init-capture](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0780r2.html) it covers this problem and possible solutions:

> With the introduction of generalized lambda capture [1], lambda
>   captures can be nearly arbitrarily complex and solve nearly all
>   problems. However, there is still an awkward hole in the capabilities
>   of lambda capture when it comes to parameter packs: you can only
>   capture packs by copy, by reference, or by... std::tuple?
>
> Consider the simple example of trying to wrap a function and its
>   arguments into a callable to be accessed later. If we copy everything,
>   the implementation is both easy to write and read:
>
> ```
> template<class F, class... Args>
> auto delay_invoke(F f, Args... args) {
>     // the capture here can also be just [=]
>     return [f, args...]() -> decltype(auto) {
>         return std::invoke(f, args...);
>     };
> }
> ```
>
> But if we try to be more efficient about the implementation and try to
>   move all the arguments into the lambda? It seems like you should be
>   able to use an init-capture and write:
>
> ```
> template<class F, class... Args>
> auto delay_invoke(F f, Args... args) {
>     return [f=std::move(f), ...args=std::move(args)]() -> decltype(auto) {
>         return std::invoke(f, args...);
>     };
> }
> ```
>
> But this runs afoul of very explicit wording from
>   [expr.prim.lambda.capture]/17, emphasis mine:
>
> > A simple-capture followed by an ellipsis is a pack expansion. An init-capture followed by an ellipsis is ill-formed.

It discusses various solutions including using a tuple:

> As a result of this restriction, our only option is to put all the
>   args... into a std::tuple. But once we do that, we don't have access
>   to the arguments as a parameter pack, so we need to pull them back out
>   of the tuple in the body, using something like std::apply():
>
> ```
> template<class F, class... Args>
> auto delay_invoke(F f, Args... args) {
>     return [f=std::move(f), tup=std::make_tuple(std::move(args)...)]() -> decltype(auto) {
>         return std::apply(f, tup);
>     };
> }
> ```
>
> Which gets even worse if what we wanted to do with that captured
>   parameter pack was invoke a named function rather than a captured
>   object. At that point, all semblance of comprehension goes out the
>   window:

This proposal was [merged in the draft standard in March](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/d307bf4578905f9a3ed9ffbedb68cef70368b1ea), so we should get this change in C++2a.

Comment: I could make it work with `tuple`: https://godbolt.org/z/8Nr2Ee. The case is a bit different: my function starts with forwarding references and not values, but the core part is the same.

Answer (score 2):

With some help (see answer and comments above) the solution I was able to find is:

```
    template<typename... ARGS>
    void emplaceWhenReady(ARGS&&... args) {
      if (_ready) {
        _a.emplace(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
      } else {
        _fInit = [this, argsCopy = std::make_tuple(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...)]() {
            auto doEmplace = [&](auto&... params) {
                _a.emplace(std::move(params)...);
            };
            std::apply(doEmplace, argsCopy);
        };
      }
    }
```